# How do I catch an event from a modal screen in R-shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, modal-dialog

I do have experience in R, but am rather new to R-shiny. I am supposed to adapt a large program with some new features. In short: I have a DataTable. When I press a button, the data in the table are shown on a modal form in another DataTable and a chart. This works like a charm. But when I change the value in the DataTable on the modal form, I can not catch the event to change them in the chart and the main form as well. Somehow the "observe" statement doesn't seem to work. My code:

```
# libraries
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)
# 
# some imaginary data
x = c(5.0, 15.0, 20.0, 25.0, 30.0)
y = c(0.2, 1.0,  1.0, 0.3, 0.1)
#
# ui
ui = fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 6,
      DT::dataTableOutput("tblData"), 
      options = list(list(width="50px", targets="_all")),
    ),
    column(width=6,
      actionButton("show", "Show", icon('chart-line'))
    )
  )
)
#
# server
server = function(input, output, session) {
  ns <- session$ns
  # create dataframe
  myData <- data.frame(x,y)
  # make dataframe reactive
  df <- reactiveValues(data = myData)
  df$myData <- myData
#
# the table on the main screen
  output$tblData <- DT::renderDataTable(df$myData,
                                        editable = TRUE,
                                        rownames = FALSE,
                                        options = list(
                                          autoWidth = TRUE,
                                          columnDefs = list(list(width = '100px', targets = "_all"))))
    
# The function to show the popup screen.
  dataModal <- function(ns) {
    modalDialog(
      withTags({
        fluidRow(
#         first column contains table  
          column(width=6,
               DT::dataTableOutput(ns("outTable")),
               outTable <- DT::renderDataTable(ns(df$myData),
                                               rownames = FALSE,
                                               editable = TRUE,
                                               options = list(
                                                 autoWidth = FALSE,
                                                 columnDefs = list(list(width = '100px', targets = "_all"))))
          ),
#         second column contains chart        
          column(width=6,
               renderPlot(ggplot(df$myData, aes(x=x,y=y)) 
                                   + geom_point(colour="red")
                                   + geom_line(linetype = "solid", colour="red"))
          )
        )
      }),
#
#     button at the bottom
      footer = tagList(
        actionButton("ok", "OK")
      ),
      title = "Graphical presentation",
      easyClose = FALSE
    ) # of modelDialog
    
  } # of function
#    
# Show modal when button is clicked.
  observeEvent(input$show, {showModal(dataModal(session$ns))
  })
#
# Get changed data from input table and store in dataframe
  observeEvent(input$tblData_cell_edit, {
    info = input$tblData_cell_edit
    i = info$row
    j = info$col
    k = info$value
    isolate(
      df$myData[i, j+1] <<- DT::coerceValue(k, df$myData[i, j])
    )
  })
#
# Get changed data from table on popup and store in dataframe
  observeEvent(input$outTable_cell_edit, {
    info = input$outTable_cell_edit
#    browser()
    i = info$row
    j = info$col
    k = info$value
    str(info)
      df$myData[i, j+1] <<- DT::coerceValue(k, df$myData[i, j])
    print(df$myData)
  })
#
# When OK button is pressed, close modal window
  observeEvent(input$ok, {
     removeModal()
   })
#    
} # end of server section
#
# run the program
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: the observeEvent doesn't work because of the ns().If you remove all the ns() and it will work. but I think your larger program may need the ns() and so you will have to figure out why and how it is a problem ...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, even without the ns() the figure does not change when I change the values in the DataTable on the modal form.

Comment: Oh i forgot, i also replaced <<- by <-

Answer (score 0):

Once you create the `outTable` and `plot` outside the `dataModal` function, it works fine.  Try this

```
# libraries
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)
# 
# some imaginary data
x = c(5.0, 15.0, 20.0, 25.0, 30.0)
y = c(0.2, 1.0,  1.0, 0.3, 0.1)
#
# ui
ui = fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 6,
           DT::dataTableOutput("tblData"), 
           options = list(list(width="50px", targets="_all")),
    ),
    column(width=6,
           actionButton("show", "Show", icon('chart-line'))
    )
  )
)
#
# server
server = function(input, output, session) {
  ns <- session$ns
  # create dataframe
  myData <- data.frame(x,y)
  # make dataframe reactive
  df <- reactiveValues(myData=myData)
  #df$myData <- myData
  #
  # the table on the main screen
  output$tblData <- DT::renderDataTable(df$myData,
                                        editable = TRUE,
                                        rownames = FALSE,
                                        options = list(
                                          autoWidth = TRUE,
                                          columnDefs = list(list(width = '100px', targets = "_all"))))
  
  output$outTable <- DT::renderDataTable(df$myData,
                                        rownames = FALSE,
                                        editable = TRUE,
                                        options = list(
                                          autoWidth = FALSE,
                                          columnDefs = list(list(width = '100px', targets = "_all"))))
  
  output$myplot <- renderPlot({ggplot(df$myData, aes(x=as.numeric(x),y=as.numeric(y))) +
                                geom_point(colour="red") +
                                geom_line(aes(linetype = "solid", colour="red"), show.legend = FALSE)
    })
  
  # The function to show the popup screen.
  dataModal <- function(ns) {
    modalDialog(
      withTags({
        fluidRow(
          #         first column contains table  
          column(width=6, DT::dataTableOutput("outTable") ),
          #         second column contains chart        
          column(width=6, plotOutput("myplot") )
        )
      }),
      
      #     button at the bottom
      footer = tagList(
        actionButton("ok", "OK")
      ),
      title = "Graphical presentation",
      easyClose = FALSE
    ) # of modelDialog
    
  } # of function
  #    
  # Show modal when button is clicked.
  observeEvent(input$show, {showModal(dataModal(session$ns))
  })
  #
  # Get changed data from input table and store in dataframe
  observeEvent(input$tblData_cell_edit, {
    info = input$tblData_cell_edit
    i = info$row
    j = info$col
    k = info$value
    isolate(
      df$myData[i, j+1] <<- DT::coerceValue(k, df$myData[i, j])
    )
  })
  #
  # Get changed data from table on popup and store in dataframe
  observeEvent(input$outTable_cell_edit, {
    info = input$outTable_cell_edit
    #    browser()
    i = info$row
    j = info$col
    k = info$value
    str(info)
    df$myData[i, j+1] <<- DT::coerceValue(k, df$myData[i, j])
    print(df$myData)
  })
  #
  # When OK button is pressed, close modal window
  observeEvent(input$ok, {
    removeModal()
  })
  #    
} # end of server section
#
# run the program
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!